# Backup solution for road warriors

Tags: backup

My users are mostly road warriors who work on their Windows laptops. I would like to have a backup solution that would copy data to a corporate server over VPN. Could is absolutely out of question. It has to:

- support flaky connections and interrupted syncs gracefully
- user should be able to throttle transfer
- Ideally, it should support multiple backup partnerships - some directories get
  backed up to server A, and some to server B.

I don't really need any sync, just  a way not to lose data. Something simple and robust is preferred to very complex and enterprisy - I can achieve versioning with server snapshots.

I don't mind paying as long as it isn't a lot (ZManda's $150/y per client is a lot)

Comment: If you don't mind using *nix-style tools (and *nix-style configuration process), [cwRsync](https://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync) is pretty robust and configurable solution...

Comment: what do you use for your corporate server backups?  Most enterprise backup solutions have options for laptop backups.  Check there first for pricing.

Comment: **ZManda's $150/y per client is a lot** -- Your data isn't worth $150 per person per year?

Comment: A splitting headache can  make you loose entire day's earning but you wouldn't pay $100 for an aspirin pack.

Answer (score 2):

I use Burp http://burp.grke.net for my backup needs, it meets your requirements and it is open source. I personally use it on CentOS and Windows 7 boxes with great success.

Comment: I agree. Burp is great. And FYI you need working_dir_recovery_method=resume in the config to resume an interrupted backup. It has a ratelimit. It uses SSL. It works with a VPN (as should any). But it sounds complicated to split directories on different servers... split per user instead.

Answer (score 0):

CrashPlan (peer-to-peer) may meet your needs.

It's not transparent but it may do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite unsure how effective it would be in your situation but I've been playing around with [Genie Timeline](http://www.genie9.com/) lately and have been able to use it over a VPN connection. It may be worth a look.